# How to convert math/big.Rat to decimal?

Tags: go, decimal, avro

I'm reading the avro file and writing the read data to mysql. But I encountered a problem. When I used [this repository](https://github.com/hamba/avro) to read the avro file, the decimal type I read was `map[string]interface{}`. When I looked inside again, there was a `big.Rat` type.So, I want to know how to convert `big.Rat` to decimal without losing accuracy.

The code to read avro files:

```
func readFile() {
    f, err := os.Open("/my/avro/file.avro")
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    dec, err := ocf.NewDecoder(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for dec.HasNext() {
        var record map[string]interface{}
        err = dec.Decode(&record)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

}
```

The solution I can think of with go

```
func NewFromBigRat(value *big.Rat, precision int) decimal.Decimal {
    flt := new(big.Float).SetRat(value)
    dec, _ := decimal.NewFromString(flt.Text('f', precision))
    return dec
}
```

Is my solution the right one? Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the decimal package you are using? I've not used avro, but the README makes it look like it does convert `big.Rat` to a decimal format. If you need another decimal type and maintain certain precision from `big.Rat`, then you solution may be just fine.

Comment: @JimB The decimal package I'm using is `github.com/shopspring/decimal`. I tested a few numbers according to my solution, and at present, I found that they are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

Last month shopspring/decimal added `NewFromBigRat`: https://github.com/shopspring/decimal/pull/288